# Beginner; Methods and Strings

Tags: java, string

Here is the code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
 public class sending {

public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String text = giveMe(first);
    System.out.println(text);
    int x = scanner.nextInt();
    x = number(x);
    skrivUt(x);
}


//method for printing on screen
public static String giveMe(String first, String second){
     first = ("Give me a number and I run down and add five to it");
     second = ("Lol");
    return first;
}

//method for doing math
public static int number(int x){
    x = x + 5;

    return x;
}

//method for printing out
public static void skrivUt(int x){
    System.out.println(x);
}   
 }
```

As you can see I am new to this and I am having a problem with the main method and the method giveMe.

I want to have giveMe work as a collection of strings that I can call when I need them.

But when I try the above example I eclipse tells me that "first cannot be resolved to a variable" on line six `String text = giveMe(first);`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You should read about variable _scope_. In the `main` method, what is `first`?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis `first` is his invisible `enum`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to use an enum and you never declared one... declare your enum like this outside your Main.

```
enum s {FIRST, SECOND} //add this

public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String text = giveMe(s.FIRST); //add the s. so it knows to use your enum
    System.out.println(text);
    int x = scanner.nextInt();
    x = number(x);
    skrivUt(x);
}
```

Then you want to modify your method to take an enum instead like this

```
public static String giveMe(s string) {
switch (string) {
case FIRST:
    return "Give me a number and I run down and add five to it";
case SECOND:
    return "Lol";
}
return "invalid string";
}
```

Comment: I think CodeCamper has it right. Just curious, when would 'Lol' be applicable?

Comment: @halal48 From what I understand it appears he wanted to make a method with a bunch of strings he can call later `I want to have giveMe work as a collection of strings that I can call when I need them` so perhaps this method will be used for a larger list of predefined strings that he wants to call in his program using `enum`. I think he will use the "Lol" string when something funny happens in his program. Perhaps when the user hits the tickle button.

Comment: I up-voted your answer and someone down-voted it with no explanation. Its obvious that he's not simply trying to do what Sireesh suggested. Or maybe I'm wrong. Adrian Larsson, can you clarify this?

Comment: @halal48 He said he wants a collection of strings to choose from. He wanted multiple strings to choose from obviously not just one.

Comment: @AdrianLarsson Enum is exactly what you want, because that is what you were trying to do when you passed in a name like that to select from a premade group of items. Basically you want to give the method a sort of multiple choice right? StringOne StringTwo et cetera, in that case you use an Enum. Secretly an Enum is just a number like 0,1,2,3 and you could make methods that way. Enum is just an easy way to remember what you assigned each number to in your method.

Answer (score 1):

Beginner, your problem is resolved.

Firstly declaration is important in java. "First"  variable is not intailzed in your block of code. Ideally it is not necessary for your scenario.

Try this

```
 import java.util.Scanner;
 public class Test2 {

public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String text = giveMe();
    System.out.println(text);
    int x = scanner.nextInt();
    x = number(x);
    skrivUt(x);
}


//method for printing on screen
public static String giveMe(){
    String first = ("Give me a number and I run down and add five to it");
    return first;
}

//method for doing math
public static int number(int x){
    x = x + 5;

    return x;
}

//method for printing out
public static void skrivUt(int x){
    System.out.println(x);
}   
 }
```

Comment: I think he wanted to be able to select from a list of strings inside of the method using an `enum` otherwise why would he create the giveMe method at all?